# JAVA Print list and getWriter() 1 line

Tags: java, arraylist

I have 4 Array lists and I would to display everything in the same line

```
for (int i= 0; i < listAttraction.size(); i++){
         resp.getWriter().println("\""+listCities.get(cptCity)+"\";\""+listAttraction.get(i)+"\";\""+listMainCategory.get(i)+"\";\""+listCategory.get(i)+"\";");                
}
```

for i = 0; 1; and 2, I will have:

```
"Cologne Germany";"Cologne Cathedral (Dom)";"Religious Sites";" Architectural Buildings; Historic Sites";
"Cologne Germany";"TeamEscape";"";"";
"Cologne Germany";"Kolner Philharmonie";"Off road/All Terrain Vehicle Trails";" Architectural Buildings; Concerts";
```

I would like to have 1 city with all attractions in just 1 line.

[EDITED] Please, note that all the lists have the same size.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: try having a nested loop, where the first for loop will loop on the city and the inner for loop for attractions.

Comment: what are three list of which elements??

Comment: I have 4 lists (just edited): city, attraction, maincatego, catego

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you are targeting for this result but try this:

```
resp.getWriter().print("\""+listCities.get(cptCity)+"\";");
for (int i= 0; i < listAttraction.size(); i++){     
   resp.getWriter().print("\""+listAttraction.get(i)+"\";\""+listMainCategory.get(i)+"\";\""+listCategory.get(i)+"\";");  
}
resp.getWriter().println();
```

Comment: Won't it throw Exception if `listAttraction.size() > listMainCategory..size()`. Nested loop will be better solution

Comment: I think his assumption is that those 3 list have the same size, but I also might be wrong.

Comment: This is very unrealistic assumption. We can provide a better solution to rule out `IndexOutOfBoundException`

Comment: He has the same assumption in his code. My code is based on it, but sure there definitely is better solution if OP posts more details.

Comment: I agree, more details will be helpful for a better solution. With this much details he can get a work around only.

Comment: Yes, they all have the same size!